# Openpyxl: Write value in the first empty cell in Column A of an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, automation, openpyxl, cell

I would like to write variables into an Excel. As the Excel is already filled with content, I would like to start writing the first variable into the first empty cell of column A. Then I jump to the right to access the next empty cell in column b and so on.

Below my code. I access the existing Excel Worksheet, loop through column A and then write the first variable to the first empty cell.

```
import openpyxl
var1 = "1"
var2 = "example"


workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/CJU3FE/Desktop/test.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.active

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=sheet.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value is None:
            empty_cell = cell
            break


empty_cell.value = var1
next_cell = empty_cell.offset(column=1)
next_cell.value = var2

workbook.save('deine_datei.xlsx')
```

Unfortunately, I cannot write var1 to the first empty cell due to AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'.

So far I could only access the last written row and overwrite the values there.

I understand that the empty cell is "NonType" but is it feasible to put in some data into the empty cell? I know that adding lines to an existing Excel file is also feasible with pandas but I would like to solve my use-case with openpyxl

Comment: The code does not correspond to the exception Are you using `values_only=True`? What does `row` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on a simple example and it works perfectly fine. I suggest you to print some debugging information (line number, type of variable, value of variable for start). Maybe you reached the end of the document, you have some merged cells, or another peculiarity of excel sheet.
At least the debug information should give you an indication of which line causes the error.

```py
r = 0
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=sheet.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    print(r, row)
    for cell in row:
        print(cell, type(cell), cell.value)
        if cell.value is None:
            empty_cell = cell
            break
    r += 1
```

Comment: When printing the loop content I see the 3 prefilled rows of the file with their content. But as soon as I try to access the empty cell in A4, I get the error. I did another test and it seems like I'm still not accessing the empty space

Comment: `r = 0
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=sheet.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    print(r, row)
    for cell in row:
        print(cell, type(cell), cell.value)
        if cell.value is None:
                    empty_cell = cell
                    break
    if empty_cell:
        break
if empty_cell:
    row_number = empty_cell.row
    column_letter = openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(empty_cell.column)
    print(f"Empty cell is in {column_letter}, row {row_number}")
else:
    print(no empty cell found.")`

Comment: No empty cell found...

Comment: Sorry for another comment, I guess I found the issue. Program only works if I add another content between the 3 prefilled rows. For example: colum 1-3 are prefilled and column 6. The program then detects that the first empty cell is A4. Now imagine I only get the 3 prefilled ones and want now want to access the fourth one. There is the issue with non-value

Comment: Congrats on finding it on your own :-) ! I suggest you take time to clarify your question/answer with examples like @Timeless proposed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that’s a good usecase for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) / [`iter_cols`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=Iter_cols#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_cols) :

```
_vars = ["1", "example"]

for col, var in zip(sheet.iter_cols(min_col=1, max_col=len(_vars)), _vars):
    for cell in col:
        if cell.value is None:
            cell.value = var
            break
```

Comment: Not tested yet cauz’ AFK but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that Openpyxl won't solve my use case. The issue is that I simply cannot add content below the last filled cell in Excel Column A. Imagine a have an excel file with content in the columns A and B in the rows 1 & 2. I tested my program by putting some random value in cell A10000. I can now access the first empty cell in column A which is A3. But as soon as I try to put in some data there (variable or hard-coded does not matter) I get the following error-code: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Smells like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem and you’re moving from your initial target/question/problem. It might be better if you can show how looks like your input spreadsheet and also precise the exact expected output.

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up: basically, openpyxl won't solve the use-case. Unfortunately, it is not possible to access the first empty cell in column A of an Excel spreadsheet. To avoid further confusion regarding XY problem: In my new script, I use Pandas to fill out the Excel sheet. So basically, I'm importing the Excel-File as a DataFrame and then add all the content I want to add via a Python-list. Afterwards Excel-file is overwritten with the Dataframe. Example:

````
excel_file = 'link to excel file'
new_line = [all variables, which will be added to empty row]
df = excel_file.append(pd.Series(new_line, index = df.columns), ignore_index=True)
df.to_excel(excel_file)```
````